# Nagios monitoring with SMS alerts via Clickatell

Tags: nagios

I'm trying to configure [Nagios](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagios) 3 to monitor a server via HTTP by searching for a certain string by using the `check_http` command as follows.

```
define command {
    command_name check_http-mysite
    command_line /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_http -H mysite.example.com -s "Some text" }
```

The HTTP check for a particular string works fine after I tested it. I have been trying unsuccessfully to configure the email-to-SMS notification by using the [Clickatell](http://www.clickatell.com/) SMTP API. How can I make it work?

I have come across an example in *[Tweak - Nagios SMS Messaging](http://www.techadre.com/content/tweak-nagios-sms-messaging)*, though I seem to miss something.

**Edit:**
I guess my explanation before was very vague. I am trying to monitor a web server in such a way that I want to search for a particular string on a page via HTTP. The command is defined in command.cfg as follows

```
    # 'check_http-mysite command definition'
    define command {
        command_name check_http-mysite
        command_line /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_http -H mysite.example.com -s "Some text" 
    }

    # 'notify-host-by-sms' command definition
    define command {
        command_name  notify-host-by-sms
        command_line  /usr/bin/send_sms $CONTACTPAGER$ "Nagios - $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$ :Host$HOSTALIAS$ is $HOSTSTATE$ ($OUTPUT$)"
    }

    # 'notify-service-by-sms' command definition
    define command {
        command_name  notify-service-by-sms
        command_line  /usr/bin/send_sms $CONTACTPAGER$ "Nagios - $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$: $HOSTALIAS$/$SERVICEDESC$ is $SERVICESTATE$ ($OUTPUT$)"
    }
```

Now if Nagios doesn't find "Some text" on the home page `mysite.example.com`, Nagios should notify a contact via SMS through the Clickatell HTTP API which I have a script for that I have tested and found that it works fine.

Whenever I change the command definition to search for a string which is not on the page, and restart Nagios, I can see on the web interface that the string was not found. What I don't understand is why isn't the notification sent though I have defined the *host*, *hostgroup*, *contact*, *contactgroup*, *service* and so forth. What I'm missing, these are my definitions,

*host.cfg*

```
define host {
    use              generic-host
    host_name        HAL
    alias            IBM-1
    address          xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    check_command    check_http-mysite
}
```

*hostgroups_nagios2.cfg*

```
# my website
define hostgroup{
    hostgroup_name   my-servers
    alias            All My Servers
    members          HAL
}
```

*contacts_nagios2.cfg*

```
define contact {
    contact_name                    colin
    alias                           Colin Y
    service_notification_period     24x7
    host_notification_period        24x7
    service_notification_options    w,u,c,r,f,s
    host_notification_options       d,u,r,f,s
    service_notification_commands   notify-service-by-email,notify-service-by-sms
    host_notification_commands      notify-host-by-email,notify-host-by-sms
    email                           myaccount@mysite.com
    pager                           +254xxxxxxxxx
}

define contactgroup {
    contactgroup_name               site_admin
    alias                           Site Administrator
    members                         colin
}
```

*services_nagios2.cfg*

```
# Check for particular string in page via HTTP.
define service {
    hostgroup_name                  my-servers
    service_description             STRING CHECK
    check_command                   check_http-mysite
    use                             generic-service
    notification_interval           0 ; Set > 0 if you want to be renotified.
    contacts                        colin
    contact_groups                  site_admin
}
```

I hope I've explained my problem clearly this time :-)

Comment: You don't really explain what problem you are having, are you getting errors with the clickatell api?

Comment: If you are using the send_sms script I think you are using: If you test the script by running it as some other user than the nagios user, remember to delete /tmp/sms.html else the wget in send_sms will fail when run by nagios. Better yet, change the send_sms script to delete the tempfile at the end.

Answer (score 2):

1. Run the `/usr/bin/send_sms` from command line to make sure the Clickatell works.
2. Take a look at `nagios.log` or `/var/log/messages` to see you have `nagios: SERVICE NOTIFICATION` whenever you got *"string was not found"* on the Web UI.

Comment: See my comment above about deleting the temporary file after running send_sms from the command line. This had me puzzled for a while.